# Typescript migration: Javascript "namespace" with multiple objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm migrating some old js to ts. The file is of form (function implementations omitted for clarity):

```
// component.js
const Component = {}; // 'namespace' for components
Component.Base = function() {}
Component.A = function() {} // extends Base
Component.A.prototype.doStuffA = function() {}
Component.B = function() {} // extends Base
Component.B.prototype.doStuffB = function() {}
Component.C = function() {} // extends Base
// ... 100 other components, 2000 lines of code
export default Component;
```

In js, to use the file, I can do:

```
import Component from './component';
// 1. Instantiate one component
const compA = new Component.A();
// 2. or create multiple components 
const threeComps = ['A', 'B', 'C'].map(name => new Component[name]() );
```

But in ts, I cannot even instantiate one component:

```
import Component from './component';
const compA: Component.A = new Component.A();
// tsc Cannot find namespace 'Component'
```

Question: What is the (quick) way to convert component.js into valid typescript, preferably keeping as many type-checks available as possible such
that

```
const compA: Component.A = new Component.B()
```

will be flagged as an error by the compiler.

I tried appending the following to the end of file:

```
namespace Component {
    interface A {};
    interface B {};
    interface C {};
}
```

This seems to compile into correct javascript, but I would have to add all properties into interfaces. Seems tedious and violation of DRY-principle.

Comment: have you got types for it?

Comment: You should `export function Base() {…}`, `export function A() {…}` instead of default-exporting an object. Then use `import * as Component from '…';`

Comment: Thanks. This worked as a quickfix. However, is there any way to get type information out of this approach without manually defining interfaces for all functions? Trying `const compA: Component.A = new Component.A();` gives error namespace has no exported member A.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to migrate to TypeScript, you could immediately take advantage of the class syntax in your `component.ts` file:

```
export class Base {

}

export class A {
    doStuffA() {}
}

export class B {
    doStuffB() {}
}

export class C extends Base {

}
```

You can consume it using an import alias:

```
import * as Component from './component';

const a = new Component.A();
```

Or you can be selective with what you import:

```
import { A } from './component';

const a = new A();
```

## Export Default / Modules Mixed With Namespaces

On the whole, the experts are saying that [export default is *a bad thing*](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/defaultIsBad.html) and that [you shouldn't mix modules and namespaces](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2017/08/stop-mixing-typescript-modules-and-namespaces/).

You *can* do it, if you feel you must. here is the example with a namespace / default:

```
namespace Component {
    export class Base {

    }

    export class A {
        doStuffA() {}
    }

    export class B {
        doStuffB() {}
    }

    export class C extends Base {

    }
}

export default Component;
```

And the use:

```
import Component from './component';

const a = new Component.A();
```